Runing WordPress docker image fail with permission error
I'm trying to make woocomerce developing env, I followed the instruction on github/woocomerce 
When I try to add plug-in or theme, I get this error:

Installation failed: Could not create directory.
/var/www/html/wp-content/upgrade.

I use pnpm -- wp-env start
I checked the files permission inside docker container and changed wp-content to be owned by www-data:www-data this what I got:
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root     19915 Apr  7 13:25 license.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      7401 Apr  7 13:25 readme.html
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root      4096 Apr  7 13:26 test-data
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      7387 Apr  7 13:25 wp-activate.php
drwxrwxr-x  9 root     root      4096 Apr  7 13:25 wp-admin
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root       351 Apr  7 13:25 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data www-data    32 Apr  7 09:31 wp-cli.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      2323 Apr  7 13:25 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      3012 Apr  7 13:25 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-r--r--  1 mohammad mohammad  6049 Apr  7 13:26 wp-config.php
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data  4096 Apr  7 14:22 wp-content
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      5638 Apr  7 13:25 wp-cron.php
drwxrwxr-x 30 root     root     12288 Apr  7 13:25 wp-includes
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      2502 Apr  7 13:25 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      3927 Apr  7 13:25 wp-load.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root     50917 Apr  7 13:25 wp-login.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      8525 Apr  7 13:25 wp-mail.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root     28427 Apr  7 13:25 wp-settings.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root     34385 Apr  7 13:25 wp-signup.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      4885 Apr  7 13:25 wp-trackback.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 root     root      3246 Apr  7 13:25 xmlrpc.php

also when I run pnpm -- wp-env start, I get this error:
✔ Ran `sudo cp /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/tests/legacy/unit-tests/importer/sample.csv /var/www/sample.csv` in 'tests-cli'. (in 1s 319ms)
ℹ Starting 'wp media import ./test-data/images/image-01.png ./test-data/images/image-02.png ./test-data/images/image-03.png' on the tests-cli container. 


Warning: Unable to import file './test-data/images/image-01.png'. 
Reason: Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2024/04. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Warning: Unable to import file './test-data/images/image-02.png'. Reason: Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2024/04. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Warning: Unable to import file './test-data/images/image-03.png'. Reason: Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2024/04. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

Error: No items imported.

✖ Command failed with exit code 1

Command failed with exit code 1

How can I fix this ?
